# Wine screws up Pulseaudio and USB audio card when already playing ALSA stream

Tags: linux, usb, wine, alsa, pulse-audio

My setup is a Thinkpad T420 with Creative X-Fi USB audio card. Everything usually works fine, I can play multiple streams and arbitrarily move streams from one audio card to another. One use case however fails miserably. When I start a video game in wine and no other audio streams are playing, then it works fine ... but when I already have been playing a HTML5 movie or have been on skype at the same time then starting wine makes a big crack and audio card vanishes from the system with a beautiful `dmesg` message. I have only observed it with wine though ...

```
[434145.910217] ALSA endpoint.c:180 cannot submit urb (err = -2)
[434146.031039] ALSA endpoint.c:838 cannot submit datapipe for urb 0, error -90: internal error
[434146.169928] ALSA endpoint.c:838 cannot submit datapipe for urb 0, error -2: endpoint not    enabled
[434215.705728] usb 1-1.5.3: USB disconnect, device number 114
```

Removing USB cable and reattaching makes the card visible again. It is very weird why would some pulseaudio error propagate so far down to the USB stack.
My system configuration is openSUSE 12.2 and pulseaudio 2.1 from the multimedia repository.

I would appreciate any advice on how to tackle this problem.

Comment: Try installing a 32 bit version of pulseaudio alongside your normal 64 bit install.  The official Opensuse rpm for pulseaudio:i586 is [here](http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/openSUSE:/12.2:/Update/standard/i586/pulseaudio-1.1-6.4.1.i586.rpm).  Wine doesn't directly support pulseaudio, but should work with the ALSA compatibility layer, provided you have 32 bit support for pulseaudio.